# Merge two numpy arrays and delete duplicates?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have one numpy array =

```
[1,6,7,9,3,5]
```

and a second numpy array =

```
[3,5,8,9,2]
```

I would like to merge these two arrays together:

```
[1,6,7,9,3,5,3,5,8,9,2]
```

and then remove the duplicates in the numpy array to get :

```
[1,6,7,9,3,5,8,2]
```

I would like to keep as much of array one as possible and take out elements of array two, that don't appear in array one, and append these.

I am not sure if it makes more sense to:

1. merge both arrays and remove duplicates.
   or
2. loop through elements of array 2, and if they don't appear in array 1 then concatenate to array 1.

I have tried using various loops but these appear to work mostly for lists, I have also tried using `set()` but this orders the `numpy` array, I would like to keep the random order form.

Comment: Do you care about order?

Comment: Yes, the order of the values in array 1 is important in this case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To join the two arrays, you can simply use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

Removing duplicates while preserving order is a bit tricky, because normally [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) also sorts, but you can use `return_index` then sort to get around this:

```
In [61]: x
Out[61]: array([1, 6, 7, 9, 3, 5])

In [62]: y
Out[62]: array([3, 5, 8, 9, 2])

In [63]: z = np.concatenate((x, y))

In [64]: z
Out[64]: array([1, 6, 7, 9, 3, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 2])

In [65]: _, i = np.unique(z, return_index=True)

In [66]: z[np.sort(i)]
Out[66]: array([1, 6, 7, 9, 3, 5, 8, 2])
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you ! can I ask you what ""_,  """after in[65] does, please?

Comment: When you use `return_index`, you get a sorted list with no duplicates, as well as the preserved indices.  Since I don't care about the sorted list, I just use `_` as a throwaway variable.

Comment: Basically, `np.unique()` is returning two results and I only care about the second.

Comment: Could I ask you one last question, please? I have my arrays with an axis=1. I have specified axis=1 in the concat function, the unique and the sort function. It appears to work as far as the sort function I am getting an error: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1, are you familiar with this?

Comment: I'm surprised the `concat` function works when you do that.  It throws that error for me.

Comment: sorry perhaps the error is in the concat function. I will look into the documentation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is slightly different way to do it also:

```
z = np.concatenate([x, y[~np.isin(y,x)])
```

Comment: Thank you, does this only concat the elements of y that aren't already in x?